# How to check status/health of Apache Ranger?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-ranger

We recently deployed Apache Ranger version 2.0.0 on Kubernetes.
We wanted to configure Readiness and Liveness probes for Apache Ranger service which is running inside pods.

Is there any health endpoint for Apache Ranger which we can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is on api endpoint to check the service status as of now, however, you can use any api to check it is connecting, for example something lie below:-

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" -u admin:admin -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://`hostname -f`:6080/service/tags/tags
```

if above call returns following value means ranger is live and serving trafic

> 200

if it returns following which means ranger is down

> 000